# dropzone.js cloning form wont allow click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js and have a form that is appended to the dom when a user clicks a button. I want the user to be able to add this form several times so am trying to clone it before adding. However, the problem I am running into is that when I append the cloned version of the form the form is not clickable (aka the user cant add an image) but when I do not use the cloned form and just use the original one in the dom it works properly. When I compare the html appended it is exactly the same... Below is the html:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/ui_config_widgets" class="dropzone dz-clickable" data-remote="true" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" id="widgetDropzone" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="uEDkc3g4sUz/Fc8n12LcpxC1AeW4dpd65lATEHvYdwY="></div>
<div class="btn-file-input">
  <input id="ui_config_widget_uuid" name="ui_config_widget[uuid]" type="hidden" value="51809ce1-0649-488f-8a6b-7b59666de111">
  <div id="delete-draft-widget">
    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div></form>
```

I am new to javascript and dropzone.js so please let me know if I am missing anything obvious. Thanks!

Comment: dropzone js makes the drag&drop and clickable div with js code, so even if you have same html it won´t mean it will work. Did you try using .clone(true, true) ?

Comment: @juvian i just tried with true, true and have same issue

Comment: Then you can try to instantiate it programmatically after copying, and add an unique id : var myDropzone = new Dropzone("form#yourNewId", { url: "/file/post"});